# Error 2147217904 No value given for one or more required parameters when querying Access from Excel

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I'm querying **Table1** in Access from Excel.  I'm filtering column `SampleType` in where clause based on three criteria checked on the **userform**.

I also need to return the number of distinct records from column `SampleID` based on selection in the where clause.

There is probably some minor problem with my code that I can't figure out. Please help. Thank you

```
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection 'dim the ADO collection class
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset 'dim the ADO recordset class
Dim dbPath As String
Dim SQLwhere As String
Dim StrSql As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim tar6 As String
Dim tar7 As String
Dim tar8 As String
tar6 = "col"
tar7 = "lun"
tar8 = "mel"

'add error handling
On Error GoTo errHandler:
'Disable screen flickering.
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

dbPath = "C:\Users\Temp1\Documents\Annie\MDL_IonTorrent.accdb"
'set the search variable

Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection ' Initialise the collection class variable

cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & dbPath

'Create the SQL statement to retrieve the data from table.

SQLwhere = "WHERE "

If CheckBox2 = True Then
SQLwhere = SQLwhere & "[Table1].[SampleType] LIKE '" & tar6 & "%" & "' AND "
'count a total district records in column SampleID.
End If

If CheckBox3 = True Then
SQLwhere = SQLwhere & "[Table1].[SampleType] LIKE '" & tar7 & "%" & "' AND "
End If

If CheckBox4 = True Then
SQLwhere = SQLwhere & "[Table1].[SampleType] LIKE '" & tar8 & "%" & "' AND "
End If

StrSql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS UniqueRecordsCount FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [SampleID] FROM [Table1]) "


 'Remove the last AND applicable

If SQLwhere = "WHERE " Then
    SQLwhere = ""
Else
    SQLwhere = Left(SQLwhere, Len(SQLwhere) - 5)
End If

StrSql = StrSql & SQLwhere


'Create the ADODB recordset object.
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset 'assign memory to the recordset

'ConnectionString Open '--5 aguments--
'Source, ActiveConnection, CursorType, LockType, Options
rs.Open StrSql, cnn


GetDistinctValue = rs("UniqueRecordsCount")
MsgBox (GetDistinctValue)

UserForm1.Controls("txtCrt6").Value = rs!UniqueRecordsCount

'Check if the recordset is empty.
If rs.EOF And rs.BOF Then
'Close the recordet and the connection.
rs.Close
cnn.Close
'clear memory
Set rs = Nothing
Set cnn = Nothing
'Enable the screen.
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
'In case of an empty recordset display an error.
MsgBox "There are no records in the recordset!", vbCritical, "No Records"

Exit Sub
End If

'Close the recordset and the connection.
rs.Close
cnn.Close
'clear memory
Set rs = Nothing
Set cnn = Nothing

'Enable the screen.
Application.ScreenUpdating = True


'error handler
On Error GoTo 0
Exit Sub
errHandler:
'clear memory
Set rs = Nothing
Set cnn = Nothing
MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure FindSampleId"
```

Answer (score 1):

The parenthesis is in the wrong place. For example, if just CheckBox2 was true then your SQL statement would end up like:

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) AS UniqueRecordsCount FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [SampleID] FROM [Table1]) WHERE [Table1].[SampleType] LIKE '" & tar6 & "%" & "'"
```

The parenthesis after `FROM [Table1])` needs to move to the very end of the SQL because otherwise you are checking the value of [SampleType] in a table which only has one column - [SampleID]

So:

```
StrSql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS UniqueRecordsCount FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [SampleID] FROM [Table1] "
```

then later:

```
If SQLwhere = "WHERE " Then
    SQLwhere = ")"
Else
    SQLwhere = Left(SQLwhere, Len(SQLwhere) - 5) & ")"
End If
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  However, the AND statement doesn't seem to be working. I get the correct number of records when I check one text box only, if I check more than one text box it always returns 0.  Should I not be subtracting 5 from the WHERE clause, something else is wrong?

Comment: Should you be using `OR` instead of `AND`, perhaps? If tar6 = "a", tar7 = "b", tar8 = "c" then using AND isn't going to return anything because nothing is like all three of those things. Using OR would return anything which starts with "a" plus anything which starts with "b" plus anything which starts with "c". If you do switch to using OR then only remove the last 4 characters from SQLwhere instead of the last 5

Comment: I will definitely try `OR`.  if instead of selecting distinct values from SampleID I wanted to count non-blank cells it that column would I have to modify the `where` clause? Or is it a simple fix? Thank you

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*)` which you have just now counts all of the records whether or not they have null values (i.e. are blank). `SELECT COUNT([SampleID])` will only count non-null values which sounds like what you need. Help on the Count function is [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Count-Function-6923a7b3-aa59-4027-ada6-d774525a4009?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&omkt=en-US)

Comment: If I use a combination of `AND` and `OR` with `OR` being last. do I subtract last 4 or 5 characters? Thank you.

Comment: Cover both options: `If (Right(SQLwhere, 4) = " OR ") Then` subtract 4 characters; else subtract 5 characters

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this same error and found out after many hours that I had copied a SQL statement from a Word document and Word had replaced standard quotes (') with specially formatted slanted quotes.  I only discovered the difference after copying the SQL statement to notepad and retrying it.